# CBConcreteCentralManager is not powered on error

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I'm trying to make a simple program that just lists the names of every connected **Bluetooth device**. I keep getting this error

```
 "CBConcreteCentralManager: (some memory address) is not powered on".
```

I have Bluetooth enabled on the iPhone 4 I am testing this on. What am I doing wrong here?

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager *centralManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self.centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripherals];

}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals{
    for (CBPeripheral *a in peripherals){ //print all of the names
        NSLog(a.name);
    }
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [central state]]); //prints 2, which is CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported
}

//irrelevant methods not shown

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

*iPhone 4* does not support *Bluetooth Low-Energy*. It's supported from *iPhone 4S* or newer, and *iPad 3* or newer and *iPad Mini*
Are you sure you're looking for *Bluetooth Low-Energy* (aka Smart Bluetooth for the "customer point of view) which work with `CoreBluetooth.framework` or juste for "classical" Bluetooth, which works with `ExternalAccessory.framework` ?